# Download and save aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saved aspx page as html it worked in my local machine but after published on the server its showing an error that "the access to the path is denied"... I tried giving access permission then also it doesn't work.. can anyone help with it? or else is there any other way to save the page in C# asp.net?...

```
string url=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string sHtml="";
HttpWebRequest request;
HttpWebResponse response=null;
Stream stream=null;

request=HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
response=(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
stream=response.GetResponseStream(); 
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(stream,System.Text.Encoding.Default);
sHtml=sr.ReadToEnd();

string path=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string textfilename=TextBox1.Text; 
string getpath=path+"\\"+textfilename+".html";
File.WriteAllText(getpath,sHtml);

if(stream!=null)stream.Close();
if(response!=null)response.Close();
```

Thanks..

Comment: where you are saving ? in DB or as an HTML file only?

Comment: I am saving as html file

Comment: Depend the way you try to save it, need some code here to tell you more.

Comment: I suspect the problem may be related to the fact you are saving it to the desktop. I'd suggest creating a new location (eg c:\webfiles\\) and saving to that location. This should avoid anything funny happening with special locations such as what/where is the desktop for the web ASP.NET user? :)

Comment: can you tel me the code to create a new location in C# Asp.net????

Comment: request=HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

this line has a typo. you are missing the opening casting parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save a file use this to get the application path

```
Server.MapPath(@"filename.txt");
```

Try this because when you only write the filename at an web server you are trying to access to a Microsoft.Net folder.

Answer (score 0):

yes make sure the folder you write to has the appropriate privileges.  IIS 5 uses ASPNET account, IIS6 uses network service.  Just give read/write to the proper account.  Is this your dev environment, or a prod environment?

Also, make sure it's pointing to a folder; desktop folder for ASPNET account probably won't exist since ASPNET account isn't a user with a users folder.

Comment: Did you change the path from thsi Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)... Desktop probably won't work since its a special account; try a different folder.

Comment: Hi your suggesstion is ok. But I need to save the page in the user's desktop whoever it is.. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't necessarily from ASP.NET, unless you use an active X control...  you can't access the client's machine from an ASP.NET server-side web site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to deploy CSS from a ZIP downloaded from the web.  Try right-clicking on the aspx file from windows explorer and checking the file properties.  One of the tabs may indicate that the file has been "blocked".  If so, there will be a button there to unblock it.